# Several bar graphs in the same panel, one for each value in data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a data frame like this:

```
  Steps Item_number   avg
   1    Item 1       172
   2    Item 1       817
   3    Item 1       110 
   4    Item 1       703
   5    Item 1       74  
   6    Item 1       12
   7    Item 1       12
   8    Item 1       87
   1    Item 2       172
   2    Item 2       817
   3    Item 2       110 
   4    Item 2       703
   5    Item 2       74  
   6    Item 2       12
   7    Item 2       12
   8    Item 2       87
   1    Item 3       11
   2    Item 3       817
   3    Item 3       110 
   4    Item 3       703
   5    Item 3       745  
   6    Item 3       92
   7    Item 3       192
   8    Item 3       831
```

And I would like a panel with the 3 different bar graph, one for each item. with x-axis representing the `Steps` and y-axis the `avg` value. Something like the image below (the bars are not matching the `avg` values provided above)

[image]

I would love to learn how to do it using ggplot and geom_bar, if possible. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, can you provide some sample data???

Comment: 5 minutes and I answer you hahahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
dataframe %>% ggplot()+
geom_bar(aes(x = Steps, y = avg, fill = Item_number), stat = "identity")+ 
facet_wrap(~Item_number, nrow = 3)+
theme_bw()
```

`facet_wrap` plots one graph for each level (I think that's what you wanted)

If you need any further explanation, tell me!